# How to scale div content based on fixed height in all devices

Tags: javascript, css, html

how to scale the #left-content div based on the window height,and i need to display all content inside the fixed #left-bg.
if i open in mobile or tablet the content is hidden .

```css
.left-bg{
background-color:red; 
  position:fixed;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  
}
.left-content{
color:#fff; 

}
```

```html
<div class="left-bg">
  <div class="left-content">
    bla bla bla
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    dajshgfkasdjgfs
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    dajshgfkasdjgfs
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    dajshgfkasdjgfs
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox.
Break up your content in 2 divs:

```
<div class="left-bg">
  <div class="left-content-top">
    bla bla bla
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    dajshgfkasdjgfs
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf</div>
   <div class="left-content-bottom">
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    dajshgfkasdjgfs
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    dajshgfkasdjgfs
    adsfjdhasgfkjsdgf
    jkdgaskhfasdkfhjl
    dasfghfdkajsfdkasf
    jghdasfkjghfkgf
    </div>
</div>
```

And flex it with space between.

```
.left-bg{
background-color:red; 
  position:fixed;
  width:50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;

}
.left-content{
color:#fff; 

}
```

Flex is magic.
See the pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNKQLW?editors=110

Is that what you were after?